# Connection refused PuTTY to VMWare workstation guest Rocky Linux

Tags: linux, unix, putty, vmware, openssh

I have Windows 10 Pro, in which VMWare Workstation 16 is installed. The guest system I use there is Rocky Linux 8.8.
The problem I’m getting Connection refused PuTTY to VMWare workstation guest OS Rocky Linux. however, this problem never occurred when I checked 2 weeks ago.

VMWare Workstation configuration:
Bridged network automatic
Vmnet0 bridged ( auto-bridging )

Guest OS:
Rocky Linux 8.8
Openssh server already install and port 22 listening
firewall-cmd configuration correctly applied
Able to ping google.com and have network within guest OS

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have openssh server running on an Ubuntu 22.04 guest inside VMware Workstation 17 Pro. Putty (Windows 11 Pro Host) connects fine just putting in the IP of the guest and shows login. So what you are trying to do works. I am trying a Kali guest but getting connection refused. I am working on that.

Comment: Try this while I am looking:   https://linuxhint.com/enable_ssh_kali_linux/

Comment: You can also access both Ubuntu and Kali with RDP - I have done that successfully multiple times even on different VMs on my network.

Comment: Any feedback from you?

Answer (score 0):

Putty Access to Ubunti and Kali is all working and tested.

**Ubuntu and like systems:**

> sudo apt-get install openssh-server
>
> sudo systemctl enable ssh
>
> sudo systemctl start ssh

Restart Ubuntu and connect with Putty (newest version MSI install)

**Kali Linux**

Please see:

[Install SSH on Kali and similar](https://linuxhint.com/enable_ssh_kali_linux/)

I know you are using Rocky Linux, but the Kali article is nicely generalized. Follow the steps.

> Ensure OpenSHH is installed.
>
> sudo apt-get install ssh
>
> sudo service ssh start
>
> sudo update-rc.d -f remove
>
> sudo update-rc.d -f defaults

Restart Kali and working

So Putty connection to Linux works but different steps depending on OS. RDP from Windows Host is much easier.

Both method work on different Linux systems, repeatedly, and in the case of RDP over a couple of years.